# Why do these arrangements of embedded c code perform so differently?

Tags: c, embedded, interrupt

**Background**

I am working with and 8052 based microcontroller. I have an LCD and and encoder wheel hooked up.  The user can navigate a menu displayed on the LCD by rotating and pressing the encoder wheel.

The rotation of the encoder wheel is interrupt based.

The direction the encoder wheel is being rotated (`encoder_turn`) is set inside of the encoder interrupt.

I call `update_lcd()` inside of a loop.

**New Responsive Code**

```
void update_lcd()                           
{

        //ENCODER TURN      
        switch(encoder_turn)
        {
            case RIGHT:
                 lcd_clear();
                 next_screen();
                 break;
            case LEFT:
                lcd_clear();
                previous_screen();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
 }

void next_screen()
{
    if(current_test_screen < screen5)
    {
        current_test_screen++;
    }

    draw_current_test_screen(); 
}

void draw_current_test_screen()
{
    switch(current_test_screen)
    {
        case screen1:
            draw_screen1();
            break;
        case screen2:
            draw_screen2();
            break;
        case screen3:
            draw_screen3();
            break;
        case screen4:
            draw_screen4();
            break;
        case screen5:
            draw_screen5();
            break;      
        default:
        break;
    }
}
```

**Old Unresponsive Code**

```
void update_lcd()                           
{

        //ENCODER TURN      
        switch(encoder_turn)
        {
            case RIGHT:
                 lcd_clear();
                 next_screen();
                 break;
            case LEFT:
                lcd_clear();
                previous_screen();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        switch(current_test_screen)
        {
            case screen1:
                draw_screen1();
                break;
            case screen2:
                draw_screen2();
                break;
            case screen3:
                draw_screen3();
                break;
            case screen4:
                draw_screen4();
                break;
            case screen5:
               draw_screen5();
               break;       
            default:
               break;
       }


 }

void next_screen()
{
    if(current_test_screen < screen5)
    {
        current_test_screen++;
    }
}
```

**The Question**

Why is one responsive and the other completely useless?

When I say responsive I am referring to the fact that when I rotate the encoder the screen change is responsive.  Both methods "work" but one is unacceptable from a usage standpoint.

Comment: Please show the definition for `encoder_turn`. Also, where is this called from?

Comment: @EdS. just think of the main loop as a while(true){update_lcd();} because that is basically what it is

Comment: @DarkFalcon encoder_turn is a volatile int defined in a separate file.  It is declared as and extern int where it is being used here

Comment: @appleskin: Ok, but it may or may not be relevant.  Since you don't know what is causing the problem, how can you possibly assume that it is not in your main loop (more specifically, how the function(s) are being called from the main loop)?  Perhaps one of the details that you think is irrelevant actually is relevant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those two pieces of code are almost equivalent, apart from one *very* subtle difference.

If you try refactoring your old code to try make it look more like your new code, you find that your old code makes one extra function call. Look carefully at the difference:

```
void update_lcd()                           
{
        //ENCODER TURN      
        switch(encoder_turn)
        {
            case RIGHT:
                 lcd_clear();
                 next_screen();
                 break;
            case LEFT:
                lcd_clear();
                previous_screen();
                break;
            default:
                draw_current_test_screen();   // <--- your new code omits this call
                break;
        }
 }
```

Try taking your new code and adding that line and see if it causes the unresponsiveness problem.

Comment: wow...that's right.  I thought it was going to be something more significant than that.

Comment: when the encoder isn't turning it is pumping out that function call

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but I suspect: Since the only thing you changed is the function nesting, `encoder_turn` is probably being cached by the optimizer. You need to mark `encoder_turn` as volatile, as the interrupt can occur and change its value at any time.